# Getting/sorting by range of numbers - syntax issue

Tags: arrays, matlab, logic, octave, boolean-logic

I'm using octave and I'm having trouble sorting out a range.  I can do the delta section by just saying include anything less than or equal to 4.  But I forget how to select a range of numbers for the Theta section.  example from 4 to 8.

PS I'm using Octave/Matlab

```
%   delta 0hz to 4 hz
    array2_deltafreq_sort=sortrows(array2,1); %used only to export txt file
    array2_deltafreq_sort_limit_idx=array2_deltafreq_sort(:,1)<=4 ;% idx to limit array
```

I tired

```
%theta 4hz to 8hz
    array2_thetafreq_sort=sortrows(array2,1); %used only to export txt file
    array2_thetafreq_sort_limit_idx=array2_thetafreq_sort(:,1)<=4 & array2_thetafreq_sort(:,1)>=8  ;% idx to limit array to
    array2_thetafreq_sort_limit=array2_thetafreq_sort(array2_thetafreq_sort_limit_idx,:);
```

but when I look at the array I get `array2_thetafreq_sort_limit = [](0x8)`

Comment: use the `&` operator... `x<=4 & x>=8`

Comment: @natan I tried your recommendation and I get [](0x8) as an answer I updated the question to show how I changed it to try your recommendation.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I had a typo in the <= >= signs, see my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    array2_thetafreq_sort_limit_idx=array2_thetafreq_sort(:,1)<=8 & array2_thetafreq_sort(:,1)>=4  ;% idx to limit array
```